# Подстраивание высоты div под высоту встроенной в него картинки

Tags: html, background

Создал элемент `div`, задал ему ширину `width 50%`. Через CSS вставил в него картинку с помощью свойства `background-image: url(....jpg);`. При этом высота `div` так и осталась `0px`. Как сделать так, чтобы она автоматически подстраивалась под высоту картинки?

Comment: css'ом без изменения логики никак.

Comment: `background-image` для того и сделан, чтоб не влиять на размер контейнера

Answer (score 0):

Что-бы получить результат нужно явно подтянуть `div` под высоту нужной картинки, но картинку показывать не обязательно:

```
<div id="out">
   <img src="bg_test.png" style="visibility: hidden;" />
</div>
```

А что-бы в этом блоке можно было разместить что-то полезное мы добавим туда еще один `div`:

```
<div id="out">
    <img src="bg_test.png" id="template" />
    <div id="int">Внутренний блок с полезной нагрузкой</div>
</div>
```

И таблица стилей:

```
img#template{
    visibility: hidden; 
    position: relative;
}

div#out {
    width:30%;
    background-image:url('bg_test.png');
    height:auto;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}

div#int {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
 }
```